# I am trying to update the output of sudo knife node edit fqdn -c /etc/chef/client.rb using bash script

Tags: json, bash, chef-infra, jq

Here is the command that I run:
`sudo knife node edit  fqdn -c /etc/chef/client.rb .` --> hit enter button then shows below output :

```
{
"name": "test",
"chef_environment": "standard_chef_environment",
"normal": {
  "httpd": {
  "fips_mode_enable": "false"
   },
"enable_fips_mode": false,
  "props": {
```

So i wanted to add few line under *props* using following command but its getting failed :

`sudo knife node edit  fqdn -c /etc/chef/client.rb |jq ‘.props |= . + { "ParameterKey": "Foo4", "ParameterValue": "Bar4" }'`

Answer (score 0):

The `props` key is nested under `normal` so you would need `.normal.props` or similar.